# Script tag in XHTML

Tags: javascript, xhtml, syntax

This might sound like a reaaaally dumb question but...

why do browsers have a fit with this syntax:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="/path/to/my.js" />
```

and want this instead

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="/path/to/my.js"></script>
```

Seems the first construct should be valid since there's no inner content to the tag..

?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)